# Passport JS authentication returning false when logging in from front-end side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express-session

I am currently developing a website using MERS stack. I am using express-session and passport.js for my back-end authentication. When I try to log in from my back-end server, the API works fine. However, when I try to send a POST request from my client-side (React), it is not authenticated.

I have tried to console.log the request from front-end and back-end, and the request is identical. One thing I notice is when I do not put an authentication middleware in my API, my front-end gets the data after being redirected to the API; the opposite happens when I put the middleware.

```
//This is my POST code
router.post(
  "/userLogin",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/api/user",
    failureRedirect: "/api/user/asktologin"
  }),
  (req, res) => {}
);

//This is my middleware
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated);
  } else {
    console.log(req);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isLoggedIn` middleware is not calling the `next` function in the stack. It should look like this

```
const authenticationMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated);
    next()
  } else {
    console.log(req);
    res.send(400);
  }
};

// Then you configure it like so
app.use(authenticationMiddleware);

// Your "router" config goes here
post("/userLogin",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/api/user",
    failureRedirect: "/api/user/asktologin"
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Do stuff
  }
);
```

For more detailed information on how to use middlewares, make sure you check out the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Comment: oops sorry I pasted the wrong code. The correct one is like the one you commented, but the main problem still persists